# Python bytearray isn't as long as it should be

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, file-io

I'm trying to read an Android yuv image represented as a raw byte file.

```
f = open(self.fn)
self.yuvArray = bytearray(f.read())
```

I know that the file contains 720K bytes, but `self.yuvArray`has only 350K.
Moreover, after trying this with multiple filesof the same format, all of which are 720K byte long (verified both in file size, and c# code returns a 720k size array), I noticed all of them are different sizes, around 350K.

I tried to see if its some kind of compression, or something, couldn't find anything.
It is vital to me to receive the correct length, regardless of if its all there, just I can't see it.

How can I read it into a 720K sized array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode (`b`).

```
f = open(self.fn, 'rb')
```

Otherwise, in Windows, carriage return, newline is converted, and a specific byte (26 == 0x1A) cause read return earlier.

```
with open('testfile', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('\r\n')
with open('testfile', 'r') as f:
    assert f.read() == '\n' # converted
```

---

```
with open('testfile', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256)))
with open('testfile', 'r') as f:
    assert len(f.read()) < 256  # len(..) == 26
```